# How to undo changes on JSpinner?

Tags: java, undo, jspinner

I need to validate the user input of a `JSpinner`, and if invalid, I need to undo (rollback) the value change. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you save the old value from the last time you validated the input, you can then reset the value of the spinner back to the last valid value.

```
boolean valid = validate(spinner);
if (valid)
    validValue = spinner.getValue();
else
    spinner.setValue(validValue);
```

Maybe something like that.

Comment: I hoped to see something more... original.

Comment: Oh, sorry.  I wouldn't bother thinking of a more imaginative way of doing it.  THis works and is fairly quick.